# Data Source wizard from Netbeans does not retrieve any table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish

I have created a JDBC connection pool and a JDBC resource using that pool. I tested the connection and it pings. I executed a SQL command in NetBeans from the service tab in the database option (it also worked).

I added the glassfish-resources.xml.

Problem:
I try to create an entity class from database in Java, using the NetBeans wizard, but when I choose the data source (JDBC I recently created) it does not retrieve any table.

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

in Netbeans, in services tab, under the connection that I created, i choose the database that i needed as default.

1) Click services tab.

2) Expand "Databases" option.

3) Expand the recently connection created.

**4) Look for the databases needed, right click and click "Set as default catalog".**

5) Go to the web project again, right click: New -> Entity classes from database.

**6) In data source drop down list, select "New data source", give a JDNI name and select the database connection needed. click finish. Tables should appear right away.**

Greetings!